# Json parsing and string management in C

Tags: c, string, json-c

Considering the following functions:

```
int get_timestamp(json_object *json_obj, double *timestamp) {
    json_object *value_obj;
    int status;
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(json_obj, "timestamp", &value_obj)) {
        if (json_object_is_type(value_obj, json_type_double)) {
            *timestamp = json_object_get_double(value_obj);
            status = JSONPARSER_OK;
        }
        else
            status = JSONPARSER_EBADTYPE;
    } else
        status = JSONPARSER_ENODENOTFOUND;
    free(value_obj);
    return status;
}

int get_display_name(json_object *json_obj, char **display_name) {
    json_object *value_obj;
    int status;
    const char* holder;
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(json_obj, "display_name", &value_obj)) {
        if (json_object_is_type(value_obj, json_type_string)) {
            // The returned string memory is managed by the json_object and will
            // be freed when the reference count of the json_object drops to zero.
            holder = json_object_get_string(value_obj);
            strcpy(*display_name, holder);
            status = JSONPARSER_OK;
        }
        else
            status = JSONPARSER_EBADTYPE;
    } else
        status = JSONPARSER_ENODENOTFOUND;
    free(value_obj);
    return status;
}

int get_organization(json_object *json_obj, char **organization) {
    json_object *value_obj;
    int status;
    const char* holder;
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(json_obj, "organization", &value_obj)) {
        if (json_object_is_type(value_obj, json_type_string)) {
            // The returned string memory is managed by the json_object and will
            // be freed when the reference count of the json_object drops to zero.
            holder = json_object_get_string(value_obj);
            strcpy(*organization, holder);
            status = JSONPARSER_OK;
        }
        else
            status = JSONPARSER_EBADTYPE;
    } else
        status = JSONPARSER_ENODENOTFOUND;
    free(value_obj);
    return status;
}
```

Used as:

```
json_object *response_obj, *idp_obj;
int status;
char *display_name;
char *organization;
response_obj = json_tokener_parse(raw_data);
json_object_object_get_ex(response_obj, "idp", &idp_obj);

get_timestamp(response_obj, timestamp);
get_display_name(idp_obj, &display_name);
get_organization(idp_obj, &organization);

free(idp_obj);
free(response_obj);
return status;
```

What happens:

1) by removing `get_organization(idp_obj, &organization);` everything seems work fine;

2) by removing `get_display_name(idp_obj, &display_name);` everything seems work fine again;

3) with the code "as is", there is an error on the `strcpy` used inside the method `get_organization`:

```
No source available for "__strcpy_sse2_unaligned() at 0x7ffff763f001"
```

I would really like to understand this behavior in order to improve my knowledge in this amazing but hard languages.

Comment: Can you show your includes?

Answer (score 0):

That error message is a debugger error message, because it's in a function which it can't locate source to. The only thing you need to do is to walk up the function call stack until you reach your code.

As for *why* the debugger stops in that function, that's really should be another question, but I'll answer it anyway: It's because of *undefined behavior* because the destination pointer you pass to it is an uninitialized local variable: `display_name`. In the code where you call `get_display_name` you declare the local variable `display_name`, but you don't initialize it. The value of uninitialized non-static local variable is *indeterminate*, and using them without initialization leads to undefined behavior.

You have basically two solutions to this problem: Either declare `display_name` as an array of a fixed size, or use make it point to valid allocated memory, for example by using `malloc`.

You will also have the same problem with the `organization` variable.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Just to understand: why in the case `1` or `2` everything seems work fine?

Comment: @vdenotaris That's the thing with *undefined behavior*, sometimes it might *seem* to work, when in reality there's probably something bad happening that you just don't notice (yet).